# How can I read excel by specifying range, I have to use apache poi package

Tags: java, excel, csv, apache-poi

I want to convert an excel file to csv in Java using the Apache poi pkg.
I have to read a specific range from the excel. Example B:G, I want to specify the starting row as well something like B3:G.
Is their a clean way to do this ?

Currently tried using the AreaReference and iterate over the cells to make sure the cell is in the area.

Example

```
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); 
AreaReference areaReference = new AreadReference("B3:G100");
Short startCol = areaReference.getFirstCell().getCol();
Short startRow = areadReference.getFirstCell().getRow();
Short endCol = areadReference.getLastCell().getCol(); 
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rowIterator.next();
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        int cellColIdx = cell.getAddress().getColumn();
        int cellRowIdx = cell.getAddress().getRow();
        if (cellColIdx <= startCol && cellColIdx <= endCol && cellRowIdx >= startRow) {
           // logic
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem using your code? What Apache POI version used?